# Azure CDN - truncating "large files" somehow?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

*Edit: This is all mysteriously working now, although I wasn't able to figure out what actually caused the issue. Might not have been the CDN at all?  Leaving this here for posterity and will update if I ever see this kind of thing happen again...*

I've been experimenting with using Azure CDN (Microsoft hosted, not Akamai or Verizon) to handle file downloads for a couple of Azure Web Apps, and it's been working fine until today, when it began returning truncated versions of a "large file", resulting in a PDF file that couldn't be opened (by "large file" I'm specifically referring to Azure CDN's [Large File Optimisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-large-file-optimization#optimize-for-delivery-of-large-files-with-azure-cdn-from-microsoft) feature).

The file works fine from the origin URL and is 8.59mb, but the same file retrieved from the CDN endpoint is *exactly* 8mb.  Which, by a suspicious coincidence, happens to be the same as the chunk size used by the Large File Optimisation feature mentioned above.  Relevant part of the documentation:

> Azure CDN Standard from Microsoft uses a technique called object chunking. When a large file is requested, the CDN retrieves smaller pieces of the file from the origin. After the CDN POP server receives a full or byte-range file request, the CDN edge server requests the file from the origin in chunks of 8 MB.
>   ... This optimization relies on the ability of the origin server to support byte-range requests

File URLs in question:

- [Origin](https://hanoiearlybird.azurewebsites.net/media/1223/hanoi-summit-program-2018-web-v3.pdf)
- [CDN](https://hanoi2018.azureedge.net/media/1223/hanoi-summit-program-2018-web-v3.pdf)

I've also uploaded the same file directly into the website's filesystem to rule out the CMS (Umbraco) and its blob-storage-filesystem stuff interfering, but it's the exact same result anyway.  Here's the links for reference.

- [Origin](https://hanoiearlybird.azurewebsites.net/largefile/largefile.pdf)
- [CDN](https://hanoi2018.azureedge.net/largefile/largefile.pdf)

In both cases the two files are binary identical except that the file from the CDN abruptly stops at 8mb, even though the origin supports byte-range requests (verified with Postman) and the Azure CDN documentation linked above claims that

> If not all the chunks are cached on the CDN, prefetch is used to request chunks from the origin

And that

> There are no limits on maximum file size.

The same issue has occurred with other files over 8mb too, although these had previously worked as of last week.  No changes to CDN configuration had been made since then.

What I'm thinking is happening is something like:

1. Client requests file download from CDN
2. CDN figures out that it's a "large file" and requests the first 8mb chunk from the origin
3. Origin replies with an 8mb chunk as requested
4. CDN begins returning 8mb chunk to client
5. CDN either doesn't request the next chunk, or origin doesn't provide it
6. Client only receives the first 8mb of the file

Or perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree. Already tried turning off compression, not really sure where else to go from here.  This is probably my fault, so have I misconfigured the CDN or something?  I've considered purging the CDN's cache but I don't really see that as a solution and would rather avoid manual workarounds...

Comment: The 1st 2 files are 8.8MB for me, and the last 2 are 9.1MB. Is this expected?

Comment: Grr, of course it starts working after I post the question :-(

Comment: Yep, now I can't reproduce it no matter what I do... Oh well, thanks for trying to help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This optimization relies on the ability of the origin server to support byte-range requests; if the origin server doesn't support byte-range requests, requests to download data greater than 8mb size will fail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-large-file-optimization

Comment: The site doesn't exist anymore but it definitely supported byte-range requests, I verified this myself by crafting a byte-range request directly to the origin (circumventing the CDN) via postman.

Answer (score 0):

This thread might be stale, but I am experiencing the exact issue right now.

AZ CDNs don't support Chunked Transfer from the source.
Also, it is dependent on the Content-length Header.

I was troubleshooting this, and found that our app uses sub_filter with nginx to replace placeholders in js files on the fly.  This disables the sending of the Content-length header.

Check that the Content-length header is being send by the source.

EDIT:

Also, what I found was that regions would behave differently.  Some would appear to recover.  But repeated with requests, the file would be truncated 2-5% of the time.

I have one region that is failing 100% after a cpl months, while North America is fine.